# select2 dropdown is not aligned properly

Tags: jquery-select2

Why is my select2 dropdown menu above the textbox and not hidden?

I am not sure what the reason is and why it doesn't work as shown on the following website: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

```
<form>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: try to add some CSS like `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`, this way all your content are same aligned. more info on [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</form>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-m7x59G4+NdYoUUKUscYq2qKkineVwmjXA/7WfXm8pukxYiFavrh9uFImpPtbmZGAnHR0rouVWWk+dgcHNurQ5g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Did you read the documentation you linked ?

Comment: I managed to fix it by putting the 2 links together.